# Change node color in spritekit

Tags: ios, colors, sprite-kit, skspritenode, vector-graphics

I have a vector illustration of a branch with a few leaves on it. I am moving the branch from the bottom of the screen to the top of the screen. But as the branch moves from the initial position (screen bottom) to the final position (top of screen) I want the branches to change color from green to orange as they move to the top. It should be a smooth transition. I have the branch and leaves as vector images. I am using spritekit(ios) for development. The branch has been attached in the link below
I do not want the color to instantly change from green to red. I want it to slowly transition from green to red as the branch moves to the top

https://ibb.co/bNH7P8

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[image]

### Images

You'll need 2 images, the green one

[image]

and the red one.

[image]

### Element

Now you need a node to hold both images

```
class Element: SKNode {

    private let green = SKSpriteNode(imageNamed: "green")
    private let red = SKSpriteNode(imageNamed: "red")

    override init() {
        super.init()
        self.addChild(green)
        red.alpha = 0
        self.addChild(red)
    }

    required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        fatalError("init(coder:) has not been implemented")
    }

    func turnRed(duration: TimeInterval) {
        green.run(.fadeOut(withDuration: duration))
        red.run(.fadeIn(withDuration: duration))
    }

}
```

### Animation

Finally you just need to invoke the `turnRed(duration:)` method

```
class GameScene: SKScene {

    let element = Element()

    override func didMove(to view: SKView) {
        self.addChild(element)
    }

    override func touchesBegan(_ touches: Set<UITouch>, with event: UIEvent?) {

        // move the element to bottom
        let bottomY = self.frame.minY + element.calculateAccumulatedFrame().height / 2
        let moveToBottom = SKAction.moveTo(y: bottomY, duration: 2)
        element.run(moveToBottom)

        // change the color
        element.turnRed(duration: 2)
    }
}
```

### Update

If you want to set the color at a given ratio between green and red then use the following code

```
class Element: SKNode {

    private let green = SKSpriteNode(imageNamed: "green")
    private let red = SKSpriteNode(imageNamed: "red")

    override init() {
        super.init()
        self.addChild(green)
        red.alpha = 0
        self.addChild(red)
    }

    required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        fatalError("init(coder:) has not been implemented")
    }

    // colorProgressionRatio must be a value between 1 (full green) and 0 (full red)
    func update(colorProgressionRatio: CGFloat) {
        guard colorProgressionRatio >= 0 && colorProgressionRatio <= 1 else {
            debugPrint("colorProgressionRatio must be a value between 0 and 1")
            return
        }

        let greenIntensity: CGFloat
        let redIntensity: CGFloat

        if colorProgressionRatio == 0 {
            greenIntensity = 0
            redIntensity = 1
        } else if colorProgressionRatio == 1 {
            greenIntensity = 1
            redIntensity = 0          
        } else {
            greenIntensity = colorProgressionRatio
            redIntensity = 1 - colorProgressionRatio
        }

        green.run(.fadeAlpha(to: greenIntensity, duration: 2))
        red.run(.fadeAlpha(to: redIntensity, duration: 2))

    }

}
```

Now you just need to call

```
element.update(colorProgressionRatio: 0.4)
```

passing a value between 0 and 1 (0 means red and 1 means full green).

Comment: I am trying to implement this as the score increments. for example when the score is between 1-20 the leaves are green but when the core is between 21-40 the leaves are red. so i need the leaves to gradually turn from green to red as the score increases from 20 to 40. so they can be green at 20 , slightly yellow at 22, and as the score increases the color shifts from green to red gradually. do you have a workaround for that ?